# Can't load my css when using spring security and thymeleaf

Tags: css, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am not able to load my css file while using spring security and thymeleaf.

Whenever i use rel="stylesheet" it gives me Strict MIME enable error.

My css file is in resources/static folder

My html file is resources/template.

HTML HEAD:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<title>Login</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/css; charset=UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link th:href="auth.css" type="text/css" href="../static/auth.css" >
<!--<link  href="../static/auth.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">-->
```

My Spring Security Code:

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**","/static/**", "/resources/**","/.*.css").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

override this method `configure(WebSecurity web)` too and modifie code like below

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll();
    }
      @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web
                    .ignoring()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**","/vendor/**","/fonts/**");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue in most cases is caused by linking css with HTML link tag. To overcome this problem you should be using thymelaf namespace `<link th:href="@{name.css}" type="text/css">` instead.